Select img src in javascript with pseudo ::before element
I'm trying to select img src trough document.querySelector and it works only for element which don't have ::before pseudo element:
document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("click",function(ev) {
        var dj = document.querySelector("#div1 > span.selected > span.swatches_image-container > img").src;
        console.log(dj);
    });


Let's say there are two span elements with img inside. It only takes these one which has not ::before element which is append dynamically while onclick this span (thick symbol overlay image)
<div id="div1" class="tawcvs-swatches oss-" data-attribute_name="div1">
    <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-white selected" data-value="white">
        <span class="swatches_image-container">
            ::before
            <img src="white.jpg" alt="white">
        </span>white
    </span>
    <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-black" data-value="black">
        <span class="swatches_image-container">
            <img src="black.jpg" alt="black">
        </span>black
    </span>
</div>

In this case I want to take src of selected white element but javascript console return second black src image. Is this because of ::before element? Is there any other way to take src of image? I could append id or class for these images, but I need to take src of these one which is in span with selected class.
Here's a working demo:


document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  var dj = document.querySelector("#div1 > span.selected > span.swatches_image-container > img").src;
  console.log(dj);
});
[data-value="white"] > .swatches_image-container::before{
  content: "bogus";
}
<div id="div1" class="tawcvs-swatches oss-" data-attribute_name="div1">
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-white selected" data-value="white">
        <span class="swatches_image-container">
            ::before
            <img src="white.jpg" alt="white">
        </span>white
  </span>
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-black" data-value="black">
        <span class="swatches_image-container">
            <img src="black.jpg" alt="black">
        </span>black
  </span>
</div>




maybe I didnt correctly understand the question.. but your code is actually printing the white.jpg picture (I edited your quetsion including the full demo as a live snippet). By the way the::before element stated as that is not actually a before pseudo-element but just text content. Of course you would require a css rule to make it a real before pseudo element but anyway it won't affect the css selector you used to fetch the element you are looking for

If you don't know querySelector gets the uppermost element in the DOM, you have to use the event argument, also if you are making swatches you should add the event listener for each swatch span


document.querySelectorAll(".swatch").forEach((swatch) => {
  swatch.onclick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.querySelector("img"))
    // Do whatever you need when you click the swatch e.g. style the outline
  }
})
[data-value="white"] > .swatches_image-container::before{
  content: "bogus";
}
[data-value="black"] > .swatches_image-container::before{
  content: "foo";
}
<div id="div1" class="tawcvs-swatches oss-" data-attribute_name="div1">
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-white selected" data-value="white">
        <span class="swatches_image-container">
            <img src="white.jpg" alt="white">
        </span>white
  </span>
  <span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-black" data-value="black">
        <span class="swatches_image-container">
            <img src="black.jpg" alt="black">
        </span>black
  </span>
</div>




Works great! Still learning javascript, I know it's simple when you already knew it. But first I need to understand, it's not so simple for someone who operate in HTML + PHP. Now I got URL of image trough var img = e.currentTarget.querySelector("img").src; Thanks

No problem man, you keep it up :)
